# How do you create a sheet for more than 1 data set to compare results in Tableau?

Tags: api, tableau-api, visualization, tableau-desktop

I have 2 data sets within the one file in Tableau, one from the 2020 Olympics game and the 2016 olympics game, what i'm trying to do is compare the data from the two years based on the total medals received by each country and possibly have it visualized within a pie chart or bar chart.

The problem is, as you can see I added one without any issues displaying what I want but if I try to add the same data from the 2022 Olympics(Team/NOC and Total), it messes the data up and both becomes unreadable.

Is there any way to display both types of data in Tableau within the same sheet?

[image: Data from one data set]

Answer (score 0):

Actually can't see from this view that there has been any messing with the data or sources.
Though I did mention on [your other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71989453/tableau-not-displaying-the-correct-figures-when-trying-to-compare-and-visualize) that as the two sets have the same structure, you could just union them (which would also be bet in a db too)

Steve