# Tableau not displaying the correct figures when trying to compare and visualize data

Tags: tableau-api, visualization, tableau-desktop, kpi

I've joined 2 data sets together, one of 2016 olympics and 2020 results and I want to create visualizations and compare the two "total" amount of medal values for each country.

When adding attributes to the sheet to create a visualization of my data, I want to compare the total amount of medals from both years for each country, it displays the Rio Olympic data correctly but when I then go to add the 2020s Olympic "Total" data figures to compare, it doesn't display the total figure for the 2020 Olympic data, I made sure to include all the figures but still doesn't display correctly.

It does the same when I do it opposite with displaying 2016s data first, it doesn't show 2020s data so the issue is not the data as far as i'm aware.

[image: 2020 and 2016 data sets joined]
Data sets joined

[image: Visualization of data] Showing data displaying correctly
[image: Adding 2020 olypmic data]Added 2020 Olympic data but doesnt display correct figures

[image: 2020 Olympic data]  2020 Olympic data should display Canada figures
[image: 2016 Olympic Data]  2016 Olympic data should display Canada figures

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an issue with your join relationship between the two data sets.
What does Tableau show when you are using just one source - remove the other source entirely.

Also, looking at your data, you'd really benefit here from unioning the sets together

Steve